# How to show SQLite data in ListView in android? search business app

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

I'm new to java programming and this website. it's my 2nd program but I'm stuck with getting SQLite data to display in ListView items. My program is showing range of business and  then display selected business in detail, sorry I can't post photos.

I'll have to describe it....

**First, ListView Business Lists:**
2 cells in each ListView item.
Left cell has business photos, right cell has 3 info: Business name(as in bold, larger text), address(in smaller text, optional) and Rating(in 5 stars)

**Second, Selected business in detail:**

Display selected business in detail full page.
Top Left cell is photo, top right cell has the same info as ListView, and it shows Description, contact info and map under the top cells.

I want to have Business name and Address and rating in the listView and the data must be from SQLite. How do I do it? Please help me. Thanks in advance!!! I have tried the following code but it didn't work.

```
public class ListViewItems extends Activity {

TextView textViewHotClubs;
Button btnSortAtoZ;
Button btnSortTopRated;
Button btnNearU;
ListView listView1;

ArrayList<Integer> images = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<String>strArray=new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<Object> ObjectArray = new ArrayList<Object>();    

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_items);

    listView1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    textViewHotClubs=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewHotClubs);
    btnNearU=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNearU);
    btnSortAtoZ=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSortAtoZ);
    btnSortTopRated=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSortTopRated);

    listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String getText=strArray.get(arg2);
            if(getText=="Code")
            {
                Intent i=new Intent(ListViewItems.this, CodeClub.class);
                i.putExtra("pushText","Code");
                startActivity(i);
            }
            else if (getText=="Club Duo")
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(ListViewItems.this,ClubDuo.class);
                i.putExtra("pushText", "Club Duo");
                startActivity(i);
            }

        }
    });

    strArray.clear();
     images.clear();

     strArray.add("Code");
     strArray.add("Club Duo");


     images.add((int)R.drawable.dragon30x33);
     images.add((int)R.drawable.rainbow30x20);




}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.list_view_items, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: For displaying data fetched from SQLite database into a listview, you should use the Cursor Adapter. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15727374/how-to-display-listview-by-using-cursor-adapter

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a **[CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html)**.

Create a Cursor which holds the data from your database.

Create the CursorAdapter which takes the Cursor object and populates the data in the UI.